# Iteration is not working

Tags: bash

I am trying to get this script to work.  It works fine when I execute it locally but it's not iterating through IP file for remote servers list in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
entry=$(cat IPfile)
for i in $entry
do
  ssh -q "$entry"
  if [[ -n $(egrep "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5" /etc/redhat-release) ]]; then
    sed -i 's/#includedir/##includedir/' /etc/sudoers
  fi
done
```

Comment: And where is that `sed` being executed? That loop is executed locally once you return from `ssh`. You need to put the command you want to execute remotely as part of the `ssh` command itself.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking for file /etc/redhat-release and grepping for content because other distros keep this file intact. Use `rpm -q --qf %{version} redhat-release`. The statement will return the version of redhat-release and throws an error when redhat-release isn't installed.

Comment: @alvits I made my answer CW. Please edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't mean `ssh -q "$i"`? `$entry` presumably expands to many values.

### Edit

I assume you want the grep/sed to occur on each server in the ip list. What your script does is to ssh into each server, then wait for instructions. This should help.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(<IPfile); do
    # Tell the remote server to start bash, but since its
    # standard input is not a TTY it will start bash in 
    # noninteractive mode.
    ssh -q "$ip" bash <<-SSH
        if [ ! -r /etc/redhat-release ]; then
            printf 'ip "%s" did not have a redhat-release file.\n' "$ip"
        elif fgrep -q 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5' /etc/redhat-release; then
            sed -i 's/#includedir/##includedir/' /etc/sudoers
        else
            printf 'ip "%s" was not rhel server 5.\n' "$ip"
        fi
    SSH
done
```

Some distros don't remove /etc/redhat-release file and make it as part of their own release package. If the script is intended to run strictly on RHEL5, check the version of redhat-release package instead.

The conditional statement will then be:

```
if version=$(rpm -q --qf "%{version}" redhat-release); then
    # it is RHEL
    if [ ${version:0:1} == 5 ]; then
       # it is RHEL 5
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You are right!  I have changed to "$i" now but still no luck.  It just does the ssh and that's it.

Comment: And what do you expect it to do? The "ssh" call will block the script until you log out and then it will edit sudoers _on the machine where you called the script_

Comment: Hi, I want it to iterate through IPlist and confirm that it's RHEL and then execute sed statement.

Comment: @Kojiro,  Thanks!  I tried to test it and it appears it's not outputting any error but it's not executing sed statement.  I had to 'SSH' though.

Comment: @user63858 whoops, there was an errant `-n` there. Try now

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `ssh -q` command is "eating" your list. You should add the "-n" option to ssh to prevent it from getting your list from the standard input.

Comment: You're probably thinking of `ssh` reading from standard input, but standard input is not read by a `for` loop.

Comment: You're right: I confused it with a similar case but with the `while read` pattern reading from a `cat`